# How to represent a compound graph using UML notations/diagrams?

Tags: uml, plantuml

I need a tool (preferably online, but at that stage I don't care anymore) which allows me to modelize relationships (similar to BPMN) which can be represented as compound graphs (though most of the times, it will be a simpler nested graph). I can't seem to achieve my goal using BPMN formalism (swimlanes are the closest but they do not allow arbitrary nesting). I am thinking to reuse UML modelization tools but I don't know enough about UML to know if UML covers my use case.

Imagine an integrated circuit which is made of chips connected with wires. So three chips : `A,B,C` and  `Chip A -> Chip B, Chip C`. Each chip has input ports and output ports, and some of the output ports of A are connected to the input ports of B, some are connected to those of C. Now `Chip A` itself can be considered as an integrated circuit, and as such can be decomposed in another graph : `Chip A :: Chip A.1, Chip A.3 -> Chip A.2`. Each `Chip A.1` can also be decomposed etc. This is what is called a compound graph. Each node of a compound graph can have children which are themselves graphs.

I do know about the Harel's and UML's statecharts formalism, which allows for hierarchical graphs to describe hierarchical nested state machines (hence any nested graph can potentially be expressed with statechart formalism), though I do not know any online tool which allow to draw statechart. The question is whether UML has a mechanism or tools which allow to specify a compound graph, and if so, what is the nesting mechanism?

#### Level 1

```
   -------
---|ChipA|---ChipB---
   |     |---ChipC---
   |-----|
```

#### Zoom on Chip A

```
-----ChipA.1---ChipA.2----   (...linked to ChipB input port
  |--ChipA.3-|         |--   (...linked to ChipC input port
```

An example of compound graph from the litterature :

[image]

Comment: I would suggest you first read about UML itself before you start looking for a specific tool. Sorry, I'll not dig into details about what compound graph is and for what purposes is it needed, but as I look at the example graphs I would concentrate on research on the following diagrams from the start: class diagram, object diagram, composite structure diagram, component diagram. If UML turns out to be what you're looking for it'll be easier then to look for a specific tool to work with.

Comment: On a second read I've decided to add answer (see below). Also as SO isn't intended to ask for a specific applications to do sth. you should change your question to "What UML diagram can replace a compund graph".
Anyway as for tool try any of the tools that support component diagram - StarUML/WhiteStarUML is one example that can do the trick. It isn't online one.

Comment: I down vote this. You ask for a graphic tool to do some job. I see the difference between compound and nested graph. You can draw that with Powerpoint. But managing them (and transitions between both) are enough for a thesis. And then: what has this got to do with a state chart - except that the latter is a graph???

Comment: You should clarify whether you want a generic compound graph tool - in which case UML isn't suitable as it deals with specific use cases - or whether you want to create a model like you chip example with blocks connected via ports and nested structure, in which case either SysML, or another EDA or systems modelling notation would be suitable.

Comment: @thomasKillian : read the question once more : The question is whether UML has a mechanism or tools which allow to specify a compound graph, and if so, what is the nesting mechanism? Or maybe read the title : How to describe a compound graph with uml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In response to your comment,

> The question is whether UML has a mechanism or tools which allow to specify a compound graph, and if so, what is the nesting mechanism?

At the infrastructure level, it uses the *Element::ownedElement* association to represent containment.  The *Namespace::ownedMember* associate subsets this association, as do the association between classes and their members, packages and nested packages, components and their contained items, and so on. All of these are conceptually compound graphs, but are not rendered in a similar way to you diagrams.

In terms of you 'Chip made up of chips', the CompositeStructures package in the UML superstructure ( section 9 of the 2.4.1 [superstructure](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.4.1/) ) uses these association to create composites, or for a domain specific example built on top of UML then SysML is the UML dialect created for systems engineering.

A systems engineering block diagram consists of blocks created with ports and connectors; blocks can have internal structure of further network of blocks. The connectors carry flows, whic can be information, energy or matter.

An example block diagram for some plant shows the custom rendering used to show owned elements in the same diagram as their containers:
[image: block diagram]

See http://www.omgsysml.org/ or http://sysmlforum.com/sysml-faq/ for further information.

Tools for sysml are listed on the http://sysml.tools/ site.

Comment: I don't know why you all go for component diagrams. The question is about **compound** graphs and initially got nothing to do with UML.

Comment: @ThomasKilian the question specifically asks for a UML solution. Although the request is for a compound graph in UML, the illustration given is for a breakdown where each component communicates with ports, which is exactly the use case for SysML block diagrams.

Comment: Well, the question resembles "what kind of hammer do you suggest to dig my garden".

Comment: @Pete, this is great. That totally solves my problem for the nested graphs. That is like 90% of my use cases, so I'll go with it. For my specific context, I can always transform my compound graphs to a nested graph. So that's wonderful. Thank you for taking the time to read and understand the question and help.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the component diagram in UML.

Your chips can be treated as components, ports will be... well, ports ;-) but also you should define some sort of interfaces (functions offered/needed by those ports). As I understand it the arrow direction depicts some sort of dependency (so the chip at the end with arrowhead provides something and thus will have a provided interface while the other end will have a required interface and a proper connection between them).

If a specific port is realised with internal structure you'll use a delegation connector for that.

Comment: I don't know why you all go for component diagrams. The question is about **compound** graphs and initially got nothing to do with UML.

Comment: @ThomasKilian yes, that's why I suggested a change to the question. Theoretically UML is not limited to software systems and it should be able to handle other systems (like physical one) as well. As question was about how to describe such model with UML diagram, that's where I go with my answer. BTW in my comment you can see I'm suggesting to look at the total of 5 different diagrams to choose from. I don't have enough knowledge about compound graphs (esp. where in particular are they used and what specifically those elements mean) to give a definite answer.

Comment: I think the question is just stupid (see my comment to Pete). UML is not about diagramming. And modeling graphs (I don't mean drawing!) is very complex. I don't see any real relation to UML with this question.

Comment: I don't know why you guys get on your high horses. If you don't understand the question or my motivations, then that's it, go on with your day. I am totally happy with Ister's answer. The question is about what UML mechanism allow to express nesting. The answer is perfect. I read about package diagram/component diagram and the thousand other diagrams/symbol/connectors in UML, and it was not clear to me at first glance which one allowed nesting. So I will now investigate component diagrams.